# Hosting Sonatype Nexus under Windows

Tags: windows, maven, nexus

As a Linux geek, it is against my better judgement to recommend or approve of the idea of installing servers under Windows (and, I guess I am also biased), but, unfortunately in this case I just have to ask for your advice concerning the performance of Sonatype Nexus under Windows.

I can see that most of the testing is done under different flavors of Linux.

I have been dealing with Nexus and Maven for quite a few years now and I'm familiar with both.

However, I would like to know your observations concerning the following:
- Is Nexus slower under Windows, than it is under Linux?

- Is the maintenance more complicated?
- What versions of Windows would you recommend using it under for best performance, if one had to use Windows?
- Are there any comparison charts in terms of speed under the different OS-s?
- Any ideas how well it will behave with a repository of over 500 GB under Windows?

Comment: My main worry would be paths on disk longer than 254 characters... Which can happen all too easily with long groupIds and artifactIds and time stamped -SNAPSHOTs

Comment: Network latency, even on LAN will likely mask any other performance differences

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Jetty in windows environments (workaround available): https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21532657-slow-download-speeds-on-windows-server-2003

Comment: And, may I ask why this question was marked for closing...?